# Code golf chromostereopsis illusion

Tags: plotting, graphics, generative-art

I am trying to maximally shorten the code (code golf) for [chromostereopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromostereopsis) illusion by Akiyoshi Kitaoka:

https://twitter.com/AkiyoshiKitaoka/status/1700061353346798019

The point is to make it: (1) identical to his image, (2) make code as short as possible. My take is below. **Can you post a shorter answer? Least number of characters wins. Please mention count of characters in your answer.** Mine is 150. I prefer to keep randomness free of fix (like `SeedRandom`). By identical image I meant basic image parameters -- size of objects and image.

```
r=RandomChoice;b=Black;s=28;f=x^2+y^2;
ArrayPlot[Table[Which[f<300,r[{b,Red}],300<=f<440,b,440<=f,r[{b,Blue}]],
{x,-s,s},{y,-s,s}],PixelConstrained->10]
```

[image]

Comment: You'll probably get better answers on [codegolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: To obtain an identical image you need to include `SeedRandom[1];` (or some other single digit seed).

Comment: @BobHanlon Actually I prefer to keep randomness free of fix. By identical I meant basic image parameters -- size of objects and image. I will note it in the question.

Comment: @Roman I am well aware of that site. But I am not interested in implementation of other than Wolfram Language.

Comment: Does this 45 character version in *Mathematica* count?  `Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6qfm.jpg"]`.  Probably not.

Comment: Just wanted to say, this is a stunning illusion!

Comment: Here's a 26 character solution that kinda sorta follows the spirit of the question: `ARPublish[Ball[]][[2,2,1]]`

Comment: @GregHurst very interesting. What do you get on output? I cannot run this unfortunately.

Comment: Sure, basically just a QR code with a disk in the middle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLfsO.png

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3009444).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

66 characters, adapted from Greg Hurst's answer:

```
Hue[2⌊2#⌋/3,1,⌊2Random[]⌋Boole@¬.44<#<.53]&~RadialGradientImage~57
```

old versions

<strike>79: `ArrayPlot@Array[{Red,1,Blue}〚2+Sign@⌊#^2+#2^2-3⌋⌊2Random[]⌋〛&,{57,57},{{-3,3}}]`</strike>

<strike>85: `ArrayPlot@Map[{Blue,1,Red}〚⌊2Random[]⌋#+2〛&,#[2√110,57]+#[10√3,57]&@DiskMatrix-1,{2}]`</strike>

[image: img]

Comment: Wow! Now if only `RadialGradientImage` wasn't so long...

Comment: You beat me to an answer with `RadialGradientImage`; I was relieved you left room to improve :)

Comment: Using `Hue` is such a creative solution. A great way to decouple the conditionals!

Comment: +1 Nicely played! Thank you :-)

Comment: Any particular reason for code golf on this problem?  I want more MMA golf!

Comment: @Adam Thank you for your answer - you win :-) Answering "I want more MMA golf!" -- show support for this by hosting some Code Golf with your own questions (ping me so i can upvote) :-) Answering "reasons": 1) I entirely share your excitement about Code Golf, so 1st reason - i just like it; 2) I thought illusion / art was nice and I wanted to see ho much code one needs to make it (see related "Kolmogorov complexity")

Answer (score 11):

84 characters:

```
str = "ArrayPlot@Array[1+Sign@\[LeftFloor](#^2+#2^2-300)/140\
\[RightFloor]Random@1\[LeftDoubleBracket]0\[RightDoubleBracket]/.{0\
\[Rule]Red,2\[Rule]Blue}&,{57,57},-28]";

StringLength @ str
```

> 84

```
ToExpression @ str
```

[image]

where I used key ideas from [Roman's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289994/125) and [azerbajdzan's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/290022/125) anwers.

Comment: +1 Thank you. `\[Rule]` should probably be `->`. Did you count unicode characters? Cool trick with floor.

Comment: StringLength for `"->"` and   `for "\[Rule]"` (or Esc -> Esc) are 2 and 1, respectively. So used the latter to save 1 character.

Answer (score 9):

115 characters (or 110, see below):

```
ArrayPlot[Array[Clip@Floor[(#^2+#2^2-300)/140]RandomInteger[]&,{57,57},-28],ColorRules->{1->Blue,0->Black,-1->Red}]
```

If we're counting characters, not bytes, then we can use [fancy `⌊…⌋` characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12900/87058) instead of the `Floor` function and do it in 110 characters:

```
ArrayPlot[Array[Clip@⌊(#^2+#2^2-300)/140⌋RandomInteger[]&,{57,57},-28],ColorRules->{1->Blue,0->Black,-1->Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your 110-character answer is 114 bytes, so still shorter than your 115-character answer.

Answer (score 9):

92 characters if colors are controllable:

```
w=49;Image[RandomInteger[1,{w,w}](1-16~#~w+2 12~#~w)/.{0->Black,1->Blue,2->Red}]&@DiskMatrix
```

86 characters otherwise:

```
w=49;Image@Transpose[1~RandomInteger~{w,w}#&/@{12~#~w,0,1-16~#~w},{3,1,2}]&@DiskMatrix
```

[image: chromostereopsis.png]

Comment: A possible variant, same characters: `w=49;Image[1~RandomInteger~{w,w}#&/@{12~#~w,0,1-16~#~w},Interleaving->0>1]&@DiskMatrix`

Comment: +1 super cool :-)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Thanks. I tried my best with constraint of  `Image` output. :)

Comment: @chyanog Nice one! I didn't use `Interleaving` version only because `True` is too long. But with your `0>1` trick it's better than mine as it's one function layer less. :)

Comment: replace `{3,1,2}` with `3\[TwoWayRule]1` to get 82 characters.

Comment: @kglr Interesting! I always forgot that new syntax!

Answer (score 8):

The symbol `` is equivalent to `->` and works well when you copy & paste the code from here to Mathematica.

Code length is 81.

```
code1 = "ArrayPlot@Array[1+Sign@⌊#^2+#2^2-3⌋⌊2Random[]⌋/.{0Red,2Blue}&,{57,57},{{-3,3}}]";
StringLength[code1]
code1//ToExpression

(* 81 *)

code2 = "21~#~57+18~#~57+1~RandomInteger~{57,57}/.{21,3Red,0Blue}&@DiskMatrix//ArrayPlot";
StringLength[code2]
code2 // ToExpression

(* 82 *)
```

[image]

```
code3="ImageApply[⌊2Random[]⌋#&,21~#~57+18~#~57/.{2Red,0Blue}&@DiskMatrix//ArrayPlot]";
StringLength[code3]
code3//ToExpression

(* 80 *)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 great thank you

Comment: I know the question asks for character count, but code golf is usually measured in bytes. This is a 92 byte answer.

Comment: Yes, I am answering the question, all posts in this thread count characters, why you chose this particular post?

Answer (score 7):

74 characters, incorporating Adam's method for rounding:

```
If[#<.45(r=⌊2Random[]⌋),Red,If[r#>.54,Blue,Black]]&~RadialGradientImage~57
```

Old versions:

77 characters:

```
If[#<.45(r=Random@Integer),Red,If[r#>.54,Blue,Black]]&~RadialGradientImage~57
```

[image]

```
StringLength["If[#<.45(r=Random@Integer),Red,If[r#>.54,Blue,Black]]&~RadialGradientImage~57"]
```

> ```
> 77
> ```

Comment: +1 `RadialGradientImage` what a wonderful find, thank you !

Answer (score 6):

Not fewer characters, but just for fun:
125 characters

```
Graphics[{RandomChoice[{t = Total[#^2 & /@ #]; 
      If[t < 300, Red, If[t >= 440, Blue, Black]], Black}], 
    Rectangle[#]} & /@ Tuples[Range[-28, 28], 2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just another variation using GaussianMatrix:

```
Image@Map[{#,0,1-3#}Sign[#-3Sign@#]&[⌊2Random[]⌋⌊10^4#⌋]&,GaussianMatrix[{28,21}],{2}]
```

> 86 Characters ..

[image]

Answer (score 5):

94 characters:

```
ArrayPlot@
 Array[RandomChoice[{t = #^2 + #2^2; 
     If[t < 300, Red, If[t >= 440, Blue, Black]], 1}] &, {57, 57}, -28]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Shortening [Melago's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/290003/125) to 87 characters:

```
ArrayPlot@
 Array[RandomChoice@{1, If[# . # < 300, Red, If[# . # < 440, 1, Blue]]&@{##}}&,
 {57,57}, -28]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I should keep pure functions in mind more often.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 57;
RandomInteger[1, {n, n}] (#[22, n] - 2 #[16, n] + 2) &@DiskMatrix // 
 ArrayPlot[#, ColorRules -> {2 -> Blue, 0 -> Black, 1 -> Red}] &
```

[image]

---

```
StringLength@"n=57;\[IndentingNewLine]RandomInteger[1,{n,n}](#[22,n]-\
2#[18,n]+2) &@DiskMatrix \
//ArrayPlot[#,ColorRules\[Rule]{2\[Rule]Blue,0\[Rule]Black,1\[Rule]\
Red}]&"
```

> 111